# Optimize for loop to count height of each column inside a 2d array numpy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

Since I need to repeat this function in a huge for loop, I was trying to find a way to optimize it, to make it faster:

```
all_cols = []
value = 0
for index in range(configuration.config['cols']):
    for y, row in enumerate(self.board):
        if y != 0 and y != 1:
            if row[index] != 0:
                all_cols.append(configuration.config['rows'] - y)
                break
for index in range(len(all_cols)):
    if index + 1 < len(all_cols):
        value += numpy.absolute(all_cols[index] - all_cols[index + 1])
return value
```

Let me explain what the function does:

`self.board` is a numpy.array declared like this:

```
self.board = np.array(
        [[0 for _ in range(configuration.config["cols"])] for _ in range(configuration.config['rows'])])
```

Now, this board represent a game state, where inside of each row and each column will be a value used for the game.

At some point, the board will look like this:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 2 1 0 0 0 5 0 0]
 [0 0 2 2 0 5 5 5 0 0]
 [0 0 2 2 0 4 0 0 0 0]
 [7 7 2 2 0 4 4 4 0 0]
 [7 7 1 2 0 0 2 2 0 0]
 [0 1 1 5 5 2 2 5 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 5 5 5 5 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 5 6 6 6 6 0]
 [1 1 4 1 0 6 6 6 6 0]
 [6 1 4 2 0 5 5 0 0 0]
 [6 4 4 2 2 6 5 0 7 7]
 [6 5 5 0 2 6 5 0 7 7]
 [6 1 5 7 7 6 0 7 7 4]
 [6 1 1 6 5 3 1 1 0 3]
 [6 2 2 6 0 3 5 0 3 1]
 [0 5 7 7 3 3 0 4 2 1]
 [2 2 7 7 2 0 5 4 5 4]
 [0 2 7 7 0 2 4 4 4 4]]
```

I want to calculate the height of each column. For the state shown above, the height of each column will be

```
15, 15, 19, 20, 14, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20
```

Basically, since you explore from the up to the bottom, the total height is 20 - the first row (ignoring the first two rows), that contains a number different from 0.

After I have all the heights I need to make the absolute difference between them in pairs, like this:

```
|(15 - 15)| + |(15 - 19)| + |(19 - 20)| + ...
```

Comment: Consider initializing `self.board` as `np.zeros((configuration.config["rows"], configuration.config["cols"]))`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist that does not help with the function but thanks for the feedback, done! The more optimitation, the better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need loops for any of your operations. First off, you can initialize the board as

```
self.board = np.zeros((configuration.config["rows"], configuration.config["cols"]))
```

Then, to compute the height of the bottom 20 rows, you can do:

```
height = self.board.shape[0] - 2 - np.argmax(self.board[2:, :].astype(bool), axis=0)
```

`.astype(bool)` converts your array into a mask of zeros and ones. `argmax` then returns the index of the first one in each column.

The differences can be computed in a vectorized manner too:

```
value = np.abs(np.diff(height)).sum()
```

Since you are computing the absolute difference, the constant offset `self.board.shape[0] - 2` won't make a difference. You can write your whole function as a one-liner:

```
value = np.abs(np.diff(np.argmax(self.board[2:, :].astype(bool), axis=0))).sum()
```

Comment: Oh, wow.. just, wow. Thanks mate, i tried with different scenarios and seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Welcome to numpy and vectorization.

Comment: If i will keep working with python i will be sure to keep learning about it, looks fantastic!

Comment: Is there a way to let np.argmax return the index of the row only if different from 0?

Comment: What do you want it to do if it's zero?

Comment: I would like to return 20. For now i used np.where and seems to work